# Nash equilibrium in Bertrand Model with Spatial Differentiation

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Consider a town with consumers represented by a closed interval $[0,2]$ with the consumers spread continuously and uniformly. There are two stores, $A$ and $B$ who sell the same product at $p_A$ and $p_B$ at no cost.

A consumer has a gross utility of 4 from having the product which is reduced by price paid and travel costs, which is determined as distance traveled. Each consumer only buys 1 unit of the product, and if the consumer does not buy from either store, he has a utility of 0. For example, if a consumer is located at $x=1.5$ and buys from store B at $p_B=1$ which is located at $x_B=2$, then his utility is $4-1-|2-1.5| = 2.5$.

Suppose that $A$ is located at $x_A=0$ and $B$ is located at $x_B=2$. Also, suppose stores much charge at $p \le 4$.

Suppose stores are profit maximizers. What are the equilibrium prices, quantities, and profits for both stores?

---

My initial thoughts are that, in this scenario, the profit functions for each store is denoted as:

$$ \pi_A=p_A+p_A(\frac{p_B-p_A}{2}) $$

$$ \pi_B=p_B-p_B(\frac{p_B-p_A}{2}) $$

We can take the first order condition for each, to get the maximizing profit.

$$ \frac{\partial \pi_A}{p_A} = 1 + \frac{p_B}{2} - p_A = 0 \implies p_A = \frac{p_B}{2} + 1 $$

$$ \frac{\partial \pi_B}{p_B} = 1 - p_B + \frac{p_A}{2} = 0 \implies p_B = 1 + \frac{p_A}{2} $$

By substituting one into the other, we have that $p_A=p_B=2$, $q_A=q_B=1$ and $\pi_A=\pi_B=2$.

I'm not very sure about this solution or the direction I took to solve it. Any advice here would be appreciated on what other direction I should try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct.  A nice 'visual' way of solving these kind of models is to look for the indifferent consumer(s).  Let $U_x(a; p_A, p_B)$, for $a \in \{A,B,\varnothing\}$ denote the utility to the agent at $x \in [0,2]$ from purchasing from $A, B$ or staying home, respectively, at a given price vector.  Let $x^*$ solve:
$$
U_{x^*}(A; p_A, p_B) = U_{x^*}(B; p_A, p_B)  \tag{$\ast$}
$$
subject to $U_{x^*}(A) \ge 0 = U_{x^*}(\varnothing)$.  But by our functional form for transport costs, $(\ast)$ is equivalent to:
$$
4 - p_A - (x^* - 0) = 4 - p_B - (2- x^*),
$$
which simplifies:
$$
p_A + x^* = p_B + (2-x^*),
$$
or
$$
x^* = 1 - \frac{p_A - p_B}{2}. 
$$
This makes sense: if both firms set equal prices, the indifferent consumer will be the middle of the line segment.

Thus profits are given by:
$$
\pi_A = p_Ax^*
$$
$$
\pi_B = p_B(2-x^*)
$$
Hence, taking first-order conditions:
$$
x^* - \frac{p_A}{2} = 1 - \frac{2p_A - p_B}{2} = 0,
$$
or
$$
p_A^*(p_B) =  \frac{2+p_B}{2}
$$
and analogously
$$
p_B^*(p_A) =  \frac{2+p_A}{2}.
$$
These intersect at $(2,2)$ as you found!  We verify now that $U_{x^*}(A;2,2) = 1 \ge 0$ so we're done!